# Inserting a JSON array from Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm wondering how I can loop insert an array value to database through Laravel.
A sample of a Json is here:

```
[{"rid":"252","recipient_id":"1","email_type":"Body","to_cc_bcc":"to","start_dte":"2016-05-18","end_dte":""},{"rid":"252","recipient_id":"5","email_type":"Body","to_cc_bcc":"to","start_dte":"2016-05-18","end_dte":""}]
```

And my controller for storing such is this:

```
public function store()
    {
        // validate
        // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
        $rules = array(
            'name'       => 'required',
        );
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // process the login
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('reports')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        } else {
            //Dump Recipient array
            $cleanRecipients = json_decode(Input::get('test'), true);
               foreach($cleanRecipients AS $value)
                    {
                            $report_recipient = new ReportRecipients;
                            $report_recipient->recipient_id       = $value['recipient_id'];
                            $report_recipient->rid       = $value['rid'];
                            $report_recipient->email_type = $value['email_type']; 
                            $report_recipient->to_cc_bcc = $value['to_cc_bcc'];
                            $report_recipient->start_dte = !empty($value['start_dte']) ? $value['start_dte'] : null;
                            $report_recipient->end_dte = !empty($value['end_dte']) ? $value['end_dte'] : null;

                    }
                        $report_recipient->save();

            // redirect
            Session::flash('message', 'Report was Successfully Saved!');
            return Redirect::to('reports');
```

What happens is that, it only stores the last set of values into the table and not all of them. I appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `$report_recipient->save();` inside your foreach loop.

Comment: Silly me..of course..more coffee..I'll check this answer after 5 more minutes since it only took a minute for the post to before getting answered. :D Thanks a heap

Answer (score 2):

Put your save() inside your loop. Also, you should do it in one transaction, to be `atomic`.

```
\DB::transaction(function() use($cleanRecipients) {
    foreach($cleanRecipients AS $value) {
        $report_recipient = new ReportRecipients;
        $report_recipient->recipient_id       = $value['recipient_id'];
        $report_recipient->rid       = $value['rid'];
        $report_recipient->email_type = $value['email_type']; 
        $report_recipient->to_cc_bcc = $value['to_cc_bcc'];
        $report_recipient->start_dte = !empty($value['start_dte']) ? $value['start_dte'] : null;
        $report_recipient->end_dte = !empty($value['end_dte']) ? $value['end_dte'] : null;
        $report_recipient->save();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.. I'll create a function in the DB afterwards.